# How to use a isolated function in a different source file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

1. How to use a isolated function in a different source file (folder)?
   I have to use `find_static_vm_vaddr` in `arch/arm/mach-XY/myfile.c`, but I don't know how to include the local "mm.h" file from `arch/arm/mm/mm.h`.
2. Or better, what is a common way to do that? I prefer to only do some changes on my custom code, instead of linux kernel inlcudes.
3. What do you think about `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`?
4. What do you think about redefinition the function in `myfile.c` ?

Any help is appreciated. If a similar issue has been solved before, give me a hint and I ld like to delete the question. Haven't found a great solution yet. Thx.

**arch/arm/mm/mm.h**

```
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU

extern struct static_vm *find_static_vm_vaddr(void *vaddr);

#endif
```

**arch/arm/mm/ioremap.c**

```
#include "mm.h"

[..]

struct static_vm *find_static_vm_vaddr(void *vaddr)
{
    struct static_vm *svm;
    struct vm_struct *vm;

    list_for_each_entry(svm, &static_vmlist, list) {
        vm = &svm->vm;

        /* static_vmlist is ascending order */
        if (vm->addr > vaddr)
            break;

        if (vm->addr <= vaddr && vm->addr + vm->size > vaddr)
            return svm;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

=====================

Update:

1.
inside arch/arm/mach-XY/myfile.c

- `#include "../mm/mm.h"`       -> does not work
- `#include "arch/arm/mm/mm.h"` -> does not work

3.
`EXPORT_SYMBOL()` -> also causes the error: undefined reference

- `arch/arm/mm/ioremap.c` -> `EXPORT_SYMBOL(find_static_vm_vaddr);`
- `arch/arm/mach-XY/myfile.c` -> `extern struct static_vm *find_static_vm_vaddr(void *vaddr);`

Comment: The function prototype should be in the header file.  Assuming `gcc`, the use the `-I` option to give the include directory, and just include the source file in your list of files when you compile (obviously you will need the full path to the source file)

Comment: this seems weird..